# Prediction with 2years data

Tags: time-series, predictive-modeling

I have this data https://data.mendeley.com/datasets/3g8dtwbjjy/1 and I'm asked to make a prediction task but I don't quite understand how I should do that. I need to use 3different algorithms for it and its my graduation project. anyone knows a procedure?

Comment: What did they teach you? I mean, the usual process for data science - machine learning should be clear already.

Comment: Thanks for the encouragement

Comment: Sorry. It was a serious question. Usually you can do your graduation project with what is in the lectures; i'll try to explain a DS process in an answer.

Comment: What are you asked to predict? My guess is grades in some of the courses.

Answer (score 0):

- Step 1: Use [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) to import and analyze the dataset
- Step 2. Use [scikit-learn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/) to make the machine learning model. Library provides many algorithms to choose from.